# Stick welder shut off

Tags: welding

I was welding with an amico 140 amp stick welder when it shut off without warning. Why did it do this? I have waited about an hour and a half and it is still unresponsive. Is there a fix? If I am not in the right place, please tell me.

Thanks, 
Amateur welder

Comment: There are innumerable reasons why a device might simply shut off.

Comment: Flagged as too broad. Please be more specific about what you're doing. It could be the welder, it could be a breaker, it could be your wiring (and I hope it isn't).

Answer (score 4):

If it restarted shortly after cooling, you may have exceeded the duty cycle. The duty cycle on the spec sheet lists it as 65% @ 110 amps and 35% @ 140 amps. What this means is at max power you can weld for you can weld for 3.5 minutes then it is required to let it rest for 6.5 minutes before resuming.  If you exceed the limits the unit shuts off to prevent overheating or damage.

Answer (score 1):

If the welder has a built in shutoff, it should have reset in that period. Some have a manual reset button you have to push to reset. If you're using an extension cord it must be rated for the application or you can cause irreparable damage to the unit. The outlet you're plugged into must have the correct breaker for the device and if not it will trip the breaker prematurely. Have you checked the circuit breaker? If it is tripped you will have to turn it off and back on and you should feel a resistance when it resets. If not, it could be a bad breaker. If you have a ohm and voltage tester you can test the output of the receptacle for voltage. There is also a way to test a welder with an ohm meter to see if it is in operable condition. You can Google for readings - I don't remember them off the top of my head.